# Get data from api using PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, http-post

I have a task of getting data from an api using PHP.
It uses **POST** request, which also sends json body.
There is not mentioning of setting any headers, which confused me. I dealt with api's using ajax before, never php. And since json goes both ways, to api and as a response from api, i'm a bit confused.

I tried doing it vanilla php way, but on various posts on SO, it is said it's not recommendable. 
Many have said that using **cURL** is correct way of doing it, so i'm guessing, it's the correct way without involving third party libraries which i(also) cannot use in this case.

My code so far:

Json body:

```
$str = '{"username":"mymail@mymail.com","password":"blah"}';
//or
$arr = [
    "username" => "mymail@mymail.com", 
    "password" => "blah"
];
```

```
function post1($url,$data){

    $ch = curl_init();

    //Example1
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $query = http_build_query($data);

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type" => "application/json"]);
    //Alt header for Example2
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
    $query = $data;

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;

}

//Example1
//echo post1($url1,$str);
//VS
//Example2
echo post1($url1,$arr);
```

Both json and non-json example produce the same error:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"80002328-0002-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"}
```

If i use alternative header for example2, it produces different one:

```
{"errors":{"":["Input string '--------------------------7abe186689ac2978' is not a valid number. Path '', line 1, position 42."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"8000232a-0002-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"}
```

In api document that i have, there is no mention of setting any headers, nonetheless, i tried even setting headers up. Both ways didn't work. Just throws an error. So either i'm missing something in cURL, or they sent me incomplete documentation. Either way, i'm not sure since i never used cURL, nor i ever used this api.

I also tried it in Postman, with headers and without, i even tried setting json body with quotation marks(it's silly, i know) just to eliminate whatever possibilities. 
None of it worked.

Mucho kudos in advance to any good people who can present me with solution based on previously stated or at least pointed me in the right direction.

**Edit1:**
Tried Brian's approach with headers, rest of code is mine.

```
function post2($url,$data){

    $headers = array(    
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    //$query = $data;
    $query = http_build_query($data);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;

}
```

I tried 4 variations of it. 
1. Data as an array and `$query = $data;`. 
Error:

```
{"errors":{"":["Input string '--------------------------ae9f656894b99247' is not a valid number. Path '', line 1, position 42."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"80002dd0-0002-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb"}
```

2. Data as string and `$query = $data;`.
   Error:

```
Internal server error
```

3. Data as an array and `$query = http_build_query($data);`.
   Error:

```
{"errors":{"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: k. Path '', line 0, position 0."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"80002dd2-0002-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb"}
```

4. Data as string and `$query = http_build_query($data);`.
   Error:

```
Warning: http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object. Incorrect value given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xmlovi\test1.php on line 56
{"errors":{"":["A non-empty request body is required."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"800022db-0002-f700-b63f-84710c7967bb"}
```

**Edit2:**
If i use `Postman` with json header:
Error:

```
Internal server error
```

If i use `Postman` without json header:
Error:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "80002dda-0002-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

**Edit3:**

Ok, i tried my original code with proven api [(repo)](https://github.com/codename11/WorldApi) which i made it myself. Both variations of original code is good, be it either json or query paramaters example. My api is tested using standard ajax(jquery and vanilla js), Postman and now even cURL from PHP. Readme.md in it is quite verbose and points in it are easily tested.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

OK, let's take the headers out for now since it didn't help.

I added in the Expect: in the httpheader because some web servers need that when using post according to the comments on curl_setopt

Have you tried to send a query string inside an array yet ? (see below)

```
function post1($url,$data){

    $ch = curl_init();

    //Example1
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));

    $query = http_build_query($data, '', '&');

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array($query));

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;

}

//Example1
//echo post1($url1,$str);
//VS
//Example2
echo post1($url1,$arr);
```

Comment: Paterson Tried it. Still errors. Care to take a look on my edited post? Maybe i missed something.

Comment: As i mentioned it, i tried also doing it with `Postman', sending json(username and password) as described, but even `Postman' throws an error. Is it possible that i got faulty api documentation?

Comment: Still same error, `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/htm ....`.

Comment: OK, i added json decode, can you try the updated function in my answer please.

Comment: This is not going work.  `http_build_query` accepts associative array which `$arr` is already is. Passing to 'json_decode' doesn't do anything. If you pass json string to 'json_decode'  and subsequently pass it to `http_build_query`, is the same as `post3($url,$arr)` without 'json_decode'.

Comment: Right, my bad,  I updated my answer, can you try the function now ?

Comment: `{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc...` error ... Also want to point to **Edit3**. I'm guessin' docs that i got, are faulty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210075/discussion-between-brian-patterson-and-veljko-stefanovic).